# How to make Facebook page events visible to people who are not logged in.

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I recently inherited a Facebook Page when I joined a band with my dad. (I guess I'm the most technically savvy amongst the group of aging rockers.) Anyway, I'm trying to make the events on the Events page visible to the public, i.e. visible to someone not logged into Facebook.

However, it's not working for me. The events say that they're public when I go to edit them, but still the Events page is blank when I navigate to it while not logged in. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Any idea as to what could be wrong?

The address to the events page is http://www.facebook.com/fourbarrelband?sk=events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single event's page is accessible for everybody, if you set the respective event to be public. (See below an example I just created.) However, if I understand correctly, you want the *list of events*, and that's not visible for anyone that doesn't use Facebook.

[image]

You can, however, invite people that are not on Facebook to your events, via email.

> You can invite people to an event who do not have a Facebook account. From the event, click **Invite Friends**. List your friends' email addresses (separated by commas) in the box labeled **Invite by E-mail Address** and click **submit**.
>
> The recipients will be able to view the event information and RSVP. They will not be able to see any other Facebook pages unless they create an account.

From [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlp4k.png).

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted to here, but it is the answer. Thanks for the info.