# Are Public Facebook events visible to people who are not logged in?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-events

It seems that the answer to this question:

[How to make Facebook page events visible to people who are not logged in.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24144/how-to-make-facebook-page-events-visible-to-people-who-are-not-logged-in)

isn't always relevant. See, for example, this public facebook event:

https://www.facebook.com/events/178688705603659/

which is not visible unless you log in to Facebook first.

Is this a new blanket policy by Facebook, requiring login before an event is visible? Is there a method to enable non-Facebook users to see a Facebook event?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not visible. The article you quote in your question shows information based on the Event Organizer's email invitations to other guests. In that scenario, the event is public, but the non-Facebook users are sent a link via email for them to access and view event details.

Your question seems more about searching and finding the public event details without being logged in. Unless you have that invitation link, you won't be able to access a Facebook Event page without logging in.

Answer (score 2):

Public events are now available to non-logged-in users at https://www.facebook.com/events/.